# How to show invisible terrain in source engine?

Tags: team-fortress-2, garrys-mod, source-engine

I want to see all items that can impede or expedite movement on a map. Invisible walls, invisible pathways, is there any way to do this ingame, and not in hammer? I want to know this for Garry's Mod and Team Fortress 2.

Answer (score 7):

One thing you can try (with `sv_cheats` on) is the console command `r_drawclipbrushes 2`. This should draw all clipping brushes as solid objects, letting you see most invisible walls/floors/ceilings/etc. Set it back to `0` to turn it off.

Comment: Why is this set to two and not one?

Comment: @Chipperyman: [Here](http://wiki.sourceruns.org/wiki/R_drawclipbrushes) is some info about it.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was just a bool. Thanks! Also, congrats on becoming a mod.